# Porting a Bash while loop to Python 2

Tags: bash, python-2.6

I'm an intern porting a Linux Bash script to Python 2.6. This script basically powers an intranet dashboard that displays data about servers. It updates every minute, and is constantly running, pretty much 24/7.

I would like some help converting the below Bash line to Python:

```
(while sleep 30; do custom_cmd > tmp.txt; cp tmp.txt index.html; rm tmp.txt; done) &
```

I have confusion converting the '&', which I know turns the while loop into a background process. The `while sleep 30` runs infinitely (as long as the user is active), and does work every 30 seconds (sleeping until then). I have already ported `custom_cmd` (which generates the html for the dashboard) to Python 2.6.

The Bash script is configured with "nohup", which I believe means the script will run even after the user logs out of the Linux machine.

That being said, how could I convert the above Bash line to Python, so that it runs as a background process, *forever*? Thank you very much.

Comment: `so that it runs as a background process, forever?` by doing `python myscript.py &`

Comment: you consider the stuff you have between `(parenthesis) &` a bash script. So you will be converting that to python, and then running that `python` script forever as @CorentinLimier mentioned

Comment: If you want to make your program constantly running, I would rather create a [daemon](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6). Easier to relaunch if the server/script crashes. You can also use `cron` and remove the while sleep 30, but the script would run every minute instead of every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The simple bash script can be written like this:

```py
from subprocess import call, PIPE
from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile
from time import sleep

def myfunc():
    while True:
        sleep(30)
        handle = SpooledTemporaryFile()
        if call(['custom_cmd'], stdout=handle) == 0:
            handle.seek(0)
            open('index.html', 'w').write(handle.read())
        handle.close()
```

You should then use the [daemonize](https://daemonize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to daemonize the function.